# Find number of lists in SharePoint Online Site Collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, count

I need a simple script that returns a count of Custom Lists and Document Libraries in a Site Collection. I don't need the items count or the files size totals, just the number of libraries.

Powershell or C# will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script:

```
$username = "user@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com"
$password = "xxx"
$SiteCollectionUrl = "https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/Sites/sitename"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"


function GetClientContext($SiteCollectionUrl, $username, $password) {
     $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
     $context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteCollectionUrl) 
     $credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $securePassword) 
     $context.Credentials = $credentials
     return $context
}




# function to loop through subsites
function getlistcount ($siteurl){
    $clientContext = GetClientContext $siteurl $username $password
    $rootWeb = $clientContext.Web
    $childWebs = $rootWeb.Webs
    $clientContext.Load($rootWeb)
    $clientContext.Load($childWebs)
    $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
    #do something on top level site
    write-host $rootWeb.url -ForegroundColor Yellow
     $count=0
    foreach ($childWeb in $childWebs)
    {

          write-host $childWeb.url -ForegroundColor Yellow
          $clientContext.Load($childWeb.Lists)
          $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
         $count+=$childWeb.Lists.Count

    }
     write-host ($count)
}


getlistcount $SiteCollectionUrl
```

Comment: this only works for subsites and doesn't give the top level count